# How to get maximum value after groupby mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Im trying to get a maximum value after im preforming a groupby clause.

```
select count(*) as count, store_id from sakila.customer
group by store_id
```

my output for this code is:

| count | store_id |
| --- | --- |
| 326 | 1 |
| 273 | 2 |

how can i get a max value from the count column? i tried several things and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

Just order your results and limit them to 1:

```
select count(*) as count, store_id from sakila.customer
group by store_id
order by count desc
limit 1
```